# Probability of picking for k times numbers lower than n in a bag containing N numbers

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

What is the probability of picking for k times numbers (x1, ..., xk) lower than n in a bag containing N consecutive integer numbers assuming that once extracted the numbers are not put back in the bag?

Three examples:

1. in a game of Bingo where N = 75, what is the probability of picking 15 (k) numbers lower than 20 (n)?
2. what happens if in the example 1) N is 7500?
3. in a card game where N = 52, what is the probability to pick once (k = 1) a card lower than 2 (n)?

Example 3) seems easy: $$P(x < 2) = \frac{4}{52}$$ where 4 are the four possible aces. But what about the other examples?

Comment: Your answer to (3) would be sensible if you had a usual pack of cards, but not if the numbers are $1,2,3,\ldots,52$

Comment: Yes, you are right. The example 3) doesn't match the description since there are duplicates. For N=52, P(x < 2)=1/52 since only 1 is lower than 2.

Comment: Consider for case 1, the numbers to be divided into two types: $1-19$ are green, and $20-75$ are red, and you are choosing from them without replacement. Have you been taught the hypergeometric distribution ?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it can be approached with hypergeometric distribution! Thank you very much!